# Почему JS выдает NaN в выражении sum = sum + variant?

Tags: javascript

Вот кусок кода:

```
document.querySelector(".but").onclick = choice;
function choice() {
  let sum = 0;
  let variant = 0;
  let radio = document.querySelectorAll(".a1");
  for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
    if (radio[i].checked) {
      variant = radio[i].value;
    }
    sum += +variant;
    document.querySelector(".out-block1").innerHTML =
      "У Вас " + sum + " баллов.";
    document.querySelector(".out-block2").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

И sum и variant являются числами, что не так?

Comment: Если вам нужны чекнутые radiobutton, то можете сразу так написать document.querySelectorAll(".a1:checked"), и не надо будет проверки делать

Comment: Переделайте вопрос. Нажмите на снипет и добавьте `html` для "минимально воспроизводимого" примера. На вскидку могу сказать что в `variant` заходить не число и при сложение просто получается дичь, которая равно `NaN`

Comment: console.log(variant) сделайте, что там? мы не видим

Comment: "*И sum и variant являются числами, что не так?*" --- значит одно из них НЕ число. Посмотри по отладке что там и где и как

Comment: @АлексейШиманский чисто технически, тс прав, у всё везде числа :), но другое дело если число являться `NaN`'ом